# Which are the best online services to run my big-data/machine-learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to run some machine learning algorithms (PCA, KNN, SMV, CNNs) with a relatively large dataset of images (>2000 rgb images) in order to classify these images.

However, my laptop is not sufficient for this task so I need to use the computational resources of an online platform (e.g. like the ones provided by AWS).

Which do you think are the best value-for-money option on Internet so that I can process efficiently/quickly my image dataset?